# Laravel left join causes unexpected results when accessing related model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

I'm trying to understand some observed behavior which doesn't make sense to me.

I've set up some contrived tables and data as below purely for the purposes of demonstrating the behavior.

### TABLE: students

id  name
1   Bob
2   Clare
3   Jim
4   Mary

### RELATIONSHIP(s)

hasMany('App\Score')
hasMany('App\Guardian')

### TABLE: guardians

id  student_id  name
1   1           bobs dad
2   1           bobs mum
3   3           jims mum
4   4           Marys mum
5   4           Marys Dad

### RELATIONSHIP(s)

belongsTo('App\Student')

### TABLE: scores

id  student_id  score
1   3           75
2   4           100

### RELATIONSHIP(s)

belongsTo('App\Student')

Looping through all students in a blade view and outputting the related guardians works as expected.

```
$students = \App\Student::orderBy('students.name')->get();
```

[image: without join]

However, when i add a left join to the scores table guardians are only displayed aginst the first record that has a related record in the scores table and they are always the first set of guardians in the table (i.e. Bob's).

```
$studentsleftjoin = \App\Student::leftJoin('scores', function($join) {
        $join->on('students.id', '=', "scores.student_id");
    })
    ->orderBy('students.name')
    ->get();
```

[image: with left join]

I would of expected the same outcome regardless of the left join.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Please forgive me if my explanation is not clear. I have created a [github repo](https://github.com/nsimms/laravel-leftjoin.git) so you may kindly recreate the issue locally.

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.
Nev.

[UPDATE: Adding view code as per request]

```
<h2>Without join</h2>
 @foreach($students as $student)
  <strong>{{$student->name}} - Guardians: </strong> <ul>
   @foreach($student->guardians as $guardian)
   <li>{{$guardian['name']}}</li>
   @endforeach
 </ul>
 @endforeach


<h2>With left join</h2>
 @foreach($studentsleftjoin as $studentleftjoin)
  <strong>{{$studentleftjoin->name}} - Guardians:</strong> <ul>
   @foreach($studentleftjoin->guardians as $guardianleftjoin)
   <li>{{$guardianleftjoin['name']}}</li>
    @endforeach
   </ul>
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Please put your view file code as well then we can debug what's wrong

Comment: I find it bad practice to do any sort of join on a model query since it will not result in that model in each row. Is there any chance the guardians are fetched by the score.id instead of the student.id?

Comment: Thanks @apokryfos its not shown in my example but the original reason for using a join is because I wanted to order by a column on the joined table.

Comment: You should do a custom `select()` then to only select columns from the original model just to make sure there's no confusing columns in your model.

Answer (score 0):

Your left join results in only `scores` table data so you need to specify grouping in your eloquent.

Add `group_by`

```
$studentsleftjoin = \App\Student::leftJoin('scores', function($join) {
    $join->on('students.id', '=', "scores.student_id");
})
->orderBy('students.name')
->groupBy('students.id')
->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Leena Patel but i'm not sure of the relevance with regards the question. My question is concerning why the related model data for guardians is effectively "broken" when my query contains a left join.

Comment: can you show what `$studentsleftjoin` returns when `dd($studentsleftjoin)` ??